# angularui bootstrap dropup not working

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I need to use a dropup menu.
This code worked perfectly with ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.10.0.js:

```
<div class="btn-group dropup">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="print('PDF')">{{text}}</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <span class="caret"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle Dropdown</span>
    </button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a ng-click="print('PDF')">Pdf</a></li>
        <li><a ng-click="print('EXCEL')">Excel</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

After upgrading to  ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.11.0.js, the dropup popup doesn't show anymore. Any help appreciated. The dropdown still works as expected.

Comment: Are you loading the core bootstrap.js library to?  If so, having the 2 libraries loaded will cause that issue.

Comment: No, from bootstrap I take only the css.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Add the `dropdown` attribute to your outer div:

```
<div class="btn-group dropup" dropdown>
```

Comment: It's working perfectly. With bootstrap tpls v. 0.10.0 this wasn't necessary. Wish there was some info on this in the documentation.